# modification in database based on a checkbox in a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have a table like this:

```
|id|name|ids|
```

lets say my table looks like this at a moment and the `ids` are something that represent some ids from other tables:

```
|1|test_name|66,980,123,33|
```

and i have a check box in a form, so when i have this check box `checked` i would like at that moment and **only** then to add for example the `88` to the `ids` in the table and when the check box is `unchecked` to no add any thing.

Any ideas? thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: You add a value to a `DB` onClick without submitting the form? And the values in the `ids` is coming from another table? Is this correct?

Comment: yes, doesn't really matter what is in `ids`, i just want an optimized way to make like a trigger or something, when check to add like a mark or something in the table because after that i wanted removed...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you want to do this regardless of whether the form is submitted, or whether the user needs to submit the form. The latter is much easier, while the former requires some reading up on AJAX.

In the latter case, assuming your checkbox is already tied to the relevant ID, you can verify it as:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox_name']) and ($_POST['checkbox_name']))
```

And if that's true, add it to the DB:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `ids` = CONTACT(`ids`, ',{$relevant_checkbox_id}')
```

Comment: but i don't want it to be in the DB after that i want it to be like a mark and then to be removed ...

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like what you're trying to do is `AJAX` requests. Everytime a user clicks on a `checkbox` You want the value of that `checkbox` to be added to a table.

Remember to add `jQuery`

**You can do something like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("checkboxId").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(":checked")){
      var id=$this.attr('id');
      var VARIABLEname=$this.val();
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'PHP_POST_SCRIPT.php',
            data:'id= ' + id + '&VARIABLEname='+VARIABLEvalue
        });
     } 
    }
  });
});
```